# Partial match in Django search

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Is there a way to match for example "123" to "1234" (or "myse" in "mysearch", case insensitive) when performing a Django search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `contains` like this

```
result = YOUR_MODEL.objects.filter(COLUMN__contains='your_text')
```

for case-insensitive use `icontains` alternative of `contains`

Comment: thanks, I actually need to converse too, that is, if I type "1234" it can still find "123". The icontains doesn't deal with this. Any ideas?